# Angular CLI Docker Development Env

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm, angular-cli

I would like to create a docker image that helps me with my Angular CLI app development. I don't want to have to install node or npm on the machine I am developing on, I just want docker to be installed. I would like to run a docker image the gives me a bash terminal where I can run `npm install`, `ng g c MyNewComponent`, `npm install New3rdPartyLib` & `ng serve` etc.

I have made some reasonable progress. So far I have the dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:19.10

WORKDIR /ui

RUN apt-get update -yq
RUN apt-get upgrade -yq

RUN apt-get install curl -yq
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install nodejs -yq
RUN apt-get install git -yq

RUN npm install -g npm
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

This I build to an image called `ag-dev-env` and fire it up with

`docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/ui -w /ui -p 4200:4200 -u root ag-dev-env /bin/bash`

This is perfect, I am able run `ng` commands and some `npm` commands

My main issue is I cannot run `npm install` as there is some issue with the directory permissions. I get the following errors.

`npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/ui/node_modules/.staging/rxjs-b34353e6/operators/pluck.js.map'`

and

```
npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --depth=1 -q -b fix-redirects git://github.com/timaschew/cogent.git /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-2b29f5f2
npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-2b29f5f2': Permission denied
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-12-23T14_36_16_225Z-debug.log
```

I have done a lot of googling and am getting no where :(

Comment: when you get this error, is it on your docker script or after in your project?

Comment: What makes this approach better than just installing Node on the host?  It seems like it brings along a lot of complexity; rather than that long-winded `docker run` command a local `npm run start` seems much simpler.

Comment: Makes no sense what you are doing, as I read this question I new it was a novice approach, if your machine is not for developing get a computer that is for developing, you do not develop code in a docker container end of story

Comment: @OdedBD - Sorry for not being clear, I get this error when I run the `docker run`, that gives me a bash terminal, then I run `npm install` inside this bash terminal.

@DavidMaze - I agree just installing Node would be simpler, at the moment I am experimenting, as sadly there are a number of legacy, environment, bureaucratic issues I am contending with. 

@BrianOgden - As I said above, I am having a little experiment as I have a number of issues to contend with, I don't really plan on developing the code in docker, just run some node/ng commands as I have issues installing node.

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/740

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a different path for the cache. The default is the home directory of the current user. Which in your case is `/root/.npm`

```
npm config set cache /var/something --global
```

I would recommend that you point the cache to a mounted directory on the host machine.

Comment: Thanks. This works at redirecting the cache, but I still get permission denied, also there is nothing in the node_modules. I think `npm install` is running some of the fetches as a different user, but I am lost as to how to take control of that.